# Is multiplication of a row by zero or a negative number allowed while performing a row operation?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

In matrices, while performing a row operation, am I allowed to multiply a row by zero or a negative number?

Comment: negative number yes, zero - usually not.

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks, so i can still perform zero multiplication?

Comment: Well, first of all, your question lacks a lot of context. I don't know what you're trying to calculate. I assume that you're solving a linear system of equations with the elimination method. If you multiply a row by zero, that row then only represents the equation $0=0$, effectively taking out information. So ... in general I don't recommend multiplying by zero.

Comment: If you are allowed to multiply a row by zero, then it follows that you are allowed to multiply every row by zero, which gets you the all-zero matrix. What do you do then, Jon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three types of row operations:

1. Multiplying a row by a constant $c\ne0$
2. Adding to a row a *different* row multiplied by a constant $d$
3. Swapping two rows

The third type is of no concern with your question.

Why the limitations on the first two types?

The idea is that row operations should be *reversible*, so when we perform a row operation, we can perform another one that “undoes” the effect of the previous one. The main reason is that such row operations don't change the solution set of a linear system (translated into matrix form), exactly because the operations are reversible.

Multiplying a row by $0$ is *not* reversible: this should be clear because doing this operation on all rows will yield the null matrix and we surely lose information. Thus is disallowed.

Adding to a row itself multiplied by $-1$ is the same as multiplying the row by $0$, so in general it is disallowed to add a row to itself multiplied by a scalar.

How do you reverse an operation of the first kind? By multiplying the same row by $c^{-1}$. What for an operation of the second kind? Say we add to row $i$ row $j$ multiplied by $d$; we reverse this by adding to row $i$ row $j$ multiplied by $-d$.

The constants $c$ and $d$ can be anything (but for the first type $c$ must be nonzero). Even $d=0$ is allowed in operations of the second kind: it is just doing nothing, which is of course reversed by doing nothing again.